# How to detect a busy audio device using Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, audio, qt5

My application uses `QSound` to play `wav` files and a 3rd party lib to use the MS SAPI interface for TTS. Now, I would like to take care that one sound is played after another. Is there a way to detect if the audio device is busy - preferably using Qt?

Comment: Does 'busy' mean busy by your .wav or busy broadly? If first then did you try `QSound::isFinished`?

Comment: Busy by either playing the wav or by speech output. So, `isFinished` will do just half of the job.